# UK visa can I use same email for two different applications?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am trying to process visa applications for my parents. I have completed their applications and booked an appointment for my father. However I am unable to book an appointment for my mother using the same email id.

Can anyone please help/clarify?

Best regards,
Rugved

Comment: I don't know; perhaps whatever server is hosting the application process is set up to refuse a second application from the same email. Consider obtaining a different email address, say a Gmail one, to use for this purpose.

Comment: And I'll add that by not naming your parents' country of citizenship, and not naming the county whose visa you're seeking for them, you prevent any of us who might know something about that country's process from sharing knowledge with you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick not many people are aware of to use the same email but write it differently. Assume your email is johndoe@gmail.com. By adding a plus sign (+) after johndoe you can then add continuous text but still go to you. For example:

```
johndoe+mom@gmail.com
johndoe+dad@gmail.com
```

This is the SAME email address. You will still receive your emails, but the "From:" field will have the additional text. I do this when I sign up for services, to find out if they are selling my email address. This will usually fool web forms into thinking they are two different emails.

The only time this does not work is when some ignorant web site programmer thinks "+" is an illegal character. For the technically-oriented people, this is allowed and legal as per [RFC 2822, Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

Comment: You can also use a dot instead of a +, at least for Gmail.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think this is true. I just tried it, and it doesn't work. It doesn't make sense either, since one could register johndoe.mom@gmail.com as a separate email address.

Comment: @MJeffryes my bad. What I meant was that you can use dots within the same address. E.g. johndoe@gmail.com can also receive emails at john.doe@ or j.ohndoe. In total you have 2^(n-1) additional emails where n is the number of characters in your email.

Comment: @JonathanReez Gmail is one of the very few services that don't care about periods in email addresses. Most others do. Because of that, I think it's a bad idea to tell people to use this as a general recommendation.

Comment: @JuanJimenez I just tested it with + and it worked perfectly! Wasn't even aware of this, thanks a lot!

Comment: and the dot method @JonathanReez said also works, tested it on my 2 gmails accounts :)