# UK Visa Application Issue after using the same email address twice

Tags: visas, uk

My dad applied for a visitor visa for himself and my mom using the same email. After the payment he logged out of his application and proceeded to fill a new application for my mom.  We have payed for both the applications and have GWF numbers as well. Now it only logs in to the second application i.e. the one of my mom. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did your father finalise his application? I doubt it’s possible to log back into an application that has been paid for, an appointment booked, and submitted. It might help you get a better answer if you explain why your father wants to access his application post-submission

Comment: He needs his account to register for submission of his documents. He wanted to complete the application for my mom before registering for biometrics and document submission. Now he can only book an appointment for my mom. Since the email address based account on the GOV of UK website was the same.

Comment: Does this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139330/uk-visa-can-i-use-same-email-for-two-different-applications help?